# error while installing darknet in windows it shows the below error?

Tags: windows, mkdir

```
C:\darknet>make
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
mkdir -p obj
mkdir -p backup
A subdirectory or file -p already exists.
Error occurred while processing: -p.
make: *** [backup] Error 1

C:\darknet>
```

Comment: This is very vague for anyone to understand, please provide the entire context of how the error is produced.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to use Linux shell commands in Windows.

Comment: Command `mkdir` on Windows does not recognize option `-p`. Instead, it creates a subdirectory named `"-p"`.